# Moving SQL db and PHP to Azure - Proving connection

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, mysqli, sqlsrv

I'm moving a existing PHP website and SQL database from a offline test environment to Azure. I'm finding it difficult to return the below simple query to prove connection between my Azure SQL database and the Azure hosted php webpage. I have tested the below in my test environment and my data is returned. When I run it in Azure only the title "Name Age" are returned. *(Note: I can't get the < ?php & ?> to appear when writing my php statement)*

```
$serverName = "tcp:DBName.database.windows.net,1443";
$connectionOptions = array("Database" => "DBName","Uid" => "DBUser","PWD" => "DBpwd");
//Establishes the connection
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
$tsql= "SELECT Name, Age
     FROM Person";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $tsql);

      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody>
          <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
          { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['Age'] ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </section>
  </tbody>
```

In Azure I have only done the initial set up of the following resources:  SQL server,  SQL database and a App Service. I have populated my SQL database (From Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) with a single table called Person with some Name and Age data and have loaded my test php page with the above code to my App Service.

I was previously using myPHPAdmin in my test environment however I want to move it to Azure to make it more secure and accessible - I know this will come with some re-write of code however i want to prove connection first. I know I am missing something obvious but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Functions `mysqli_` are for MySQL, not for SQL Server. You need to use PHP Driver for SQL Server to connect to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using functions from two different PHP extensions (`sqlsrv_connect()`and  `mysqli_query()` \ `mysqli_fetch_array()`). To connect to SQL Server you need only `sqlsrv_` functions (part of PHP Driver for SQL Server).

The following script, based on your attempt, demonstrates how to connect to SQL Server and retrieve the data:

```
<?php
// Connection
$serverName = "tcp:DBName.database.windows.net,1443";
$connectionOptions = array("Database" => "DBName", "Uid" => "DBUser", "PWD" => "DBpwd");
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($connection === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   
// Statement
$tsql = "SELECT Name, Age FROM Person";
$query = sqlsrv_query($connection, $tsql);
if ($query === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   
?>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php 
// Data
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Age'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
</tbody>
<?php
// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
sqlsrv_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. Can see now how i was using the different extensions incorrectly.